# How to show Backtrace for emacs?

Tags: scala, emacs, emacs-prelude

I encounter an error:

```
scala-block-indentation: Wrong type argument: number-or-marker-p, nil
```

Whenever I click <kbd>tab</kbd> for indent in `scala-mode`.

I don't know where goes wrong in the code but want to fix it. However, I can only see this error in `*Message*` buffer without details. I tried to see this error in Backtrace but didn't know how.  I tried (1) `-debug-init` to launch emacs (2) `debug-on-entry` command for `scala-block-indentation` but neither of them works.

Does anyone have ideas about how to enable BackTrace/Debugger for this function?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I have not used scala under emacs to tell if this can help you.  But try `(setq debug-on-error t)` in your `.emacs`, or simply do `M-: (setq debug-on-error t)` to try for the current emacs session only.

Comment: `M-x toggle-debug-on-error` is more convenient in the interactive case.